# 50 MB increase in memory consumption on displaying an Image

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

I have a JavaFX application (Swing users input might also help) which is Image gallery basically. It watches a folder, and as soon as any Image is added, the Image is displayed on the screen.

Sooner as more Images got added, the application memory consumption only grew bigger. On profiling, I have observed that on adding an Image (size 1.3 MB), memory consumption increased by about 50 MB. The class that holds Image is a simple `ImageView` that holds an `Image`. 
Does any one have similar experiences? The behavior is same on Windows & Mac

PS: I know any code here will help, but there is nothing much to be shown. As I said there is a List of ImageView which holds Image. List of ImageView is binded to another `List` say `l1`. On detecting an Image, image is added to `l1` and so is added to the actual list which is displayed on screen

EDIT:

I just tried a sample code. I have observed that, on every Iamge it loads (2.3 MB in this case), there is a memory increase of 12 MB each:

```
package side;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

public static void main(String... args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ScrollBar bar = new ScrollBar();
    bar.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);


    final VBox box = new VBox();
    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().addAll(box, bar);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Layout Sample");
    primaryStage.show();


    for (int ik = 0; ik < 6; ik++) {
        System.out.println("1");
        ImageView i = new ImageView();
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Jatin\\Documents\\BarcodeNew\\w.png"));
        Image im = new Image(is);
        i.setImage(im);
        box.getChildren().add(i);
        is.close();
    }

    //r.close();


}
```

}

Comment: If you are only using a thumbnail for display purpose then there is no need to store the image at full resolution, Instead a scaled down version would work.

Comment: Yes. That I will do. But still, for an Iamge of size 1.3MB why so much increase??

Comment: Check your code for memory leaks, A profiler would help here.

Comment: Check ***[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868913/java-images-take-up-too-much-memory)*** post too.

Comment: Read this, I think there are same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890351/high-memory-consumption-by-an-image

Comment: Consider to use the new Automatic Resource Management feature of Java SE 7 to manage your streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found two issues:

1. I wasn't closing my stream.
2. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890351/high-memory-consumption-by-an-image)

> Remember that the file size of a PNG image and the memory consumption of an uncompressed image in memory are very different.

On specifying the size of the `Image` it all works well.